# MATLAB: overriding table() methods

Tags: matlab, oop, methods, overriding

SETUP Win7 64b, R2015b, 16 GB of RAM, CPU i7-2700

The `table()` is a [fundamental Matlab class](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html) which is also *sealed*, hence I cannot subclass it.

I want to **fix** some methods of this class and **add new** ones. 
For instance, `table.disp()` is fundamentally broken, e.g. try NOT `disp(table(rand(1e7,1)))`, or forget the `;` in the command window. The variable takes only 76 MB in RAM but the display is unbuffered and it will stall your system!

1. Can I **override** methods like `table.disp()` without writing into `matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@table`?
2. Can I **extend** the table class with a new method under `C:\MATLAB\@table\ismatrixlike.m`? Why do I get

   ```
   ismatrixlike(table)
   Undefined function 'ismatrixlike' for input arguments of type 'table'.
   ```

   Obviously, I did

   ```
   addpath C:\MATLAB\
   rehash toolboxcache
   ```

   I also tried `clear all`.

   The path has (alphabetic) precedence over `matlabroot`, but is missing a `table.m` class definition. If I add the native class defition to `C:\MATLAB\@table`, then I can run my new method (after a `clear all`). However:

   ```
   >> methods(table)

   Methods for class table:

   classVarNames   ismatrixlike    table           varfun          
   convertColumn   renameVarNames  unstack
   ```

   only lists the methods in the new `\@table` folder, even though (some of) the old methods still work, e.g.

   ```
   size(table)
   ```

   This partly solves the problem, since now, the native `\@table\private` folder is not accessible anymore and therefore many native methods are broken!

Why am I doing this? Because I do not want to wait another 2 years before the `table()` is fixed. I already lost entire days because I simply forgot a `;` in the command window and I cannot force a restart on my pc if it is running multiday simulations, but I have to wait for the disk-swap to end :(.

**APPENDIX**
More context about `disp(table(rand(1e7,1)))`. This is what happens when I hit it (and luckily I am fast enough to CTRL-C out of it):

[image]

The culprit is line 172 of `table.disp()` which converts the numeric array into a cellstring (with the padding too!):

```
[cells, err, isLeft] = sprintfc(f, x, b);
```

Comment: Getting Matlab to do anything that's *not* already in a toolbox... guaranteed pain. Abandon all hope, ye who enter here!

Comment: Note that `istable` is not a  method of the table class but rather it's own function which calls `isa(t, 'table')`.

Comment: @Suever thanks for noticing that. I will change it to `table.size()`

Comment: One thing to note - I found I could CTRL-C out of that table `display` example you were complaining about...

Comment: A question: what does `ismatrixlike` do that is different to the existing `ismatrix`?

Comment: @Edric Did you CTRL-C out of it when it was already priting numbers in the command window or did you CTRL-C out immediately? How much RAM do you have and what OS are you using? Did your table have 10 million rows?

Comment: @Edric `ismatrix()` tests for numeric input and table is table class (hence `ismatrix(table())` is always false). Also, since you can have `table(rand(3,2), rand(3,1))`, i.e. the first variable has 2 columns itself already, a matrix-like table, is basically a matrix with headers on top. Finally, `ismatrixlike()` also tests that all variables of a table are of the same class. I need that function to define the transpose of a matrix-like table.

Comment: @Oleg `ismatrix` doesn't check for numeric input (at least it doesn't in R2015b, I haven't checked back to earlier releases), so `ismatrix(table())` returns `true` (I did the check just to be sure ...). Of course, it doesn't tell you about your additional constraints. Anyway, personally I'd write a _function_ called `ismatrixlike` and switch on the return of `istable`.

Comment: @Oleg for the CTRL-C experiment, I ran the 1e7 row reproduction using R2015b on GLNXA64 on a machine with 24GB RAM. I let the output start printing out (which I agree did make my machine pretty unresponsive), but then I was able to CTRL-C while that was happening.

Comment: @Edric Sorry for the `ismatrix()` confusion, you are right. However, it does not serve my purpose since it returns true for `ismatrix(table(rand(2),rand(2,1)))` which has two columns for the first variable. That would make it tricky to define reshape-type operations on such a table. For the `disp()` problem, please see my memory screenshot above. In your case, probably, 24GB are enough to handle that size...you can try scaling it up to 2e7 rows and so forth.

Comment: I've started experimenting as well. It's easy to intercept methods for other built in types like `double` by simply adding a directory on the path with `@double\plus.m` where `plus.m` is the operator or function you'd like to overwrite. However, this does not work with table. No idea why. Did you have success in meantime?

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting with several alternatives, I adopted the solution that intereferes the least with Matlab's native `@table` implementation and it's easily removed if things go awry.

The solution:

- **copy** the whole `@table` folder, i.e. `fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','datatypes','@table')`, into a destination where you have *write* permissions.

  I picked the *destination* to be `fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','local','myfiles')` since I do not have to bother with OS cross-compatibility, i.e. `matlabroot` takes care of that for me.
- **paste** into the *destination* your `@table` folder with the new, overloaded and overriding methods (partially overwriting the copied original files)
- **add** the *destination* to the matlab path, before the original `@table`, e.g. `addpath your_destination -begin`

Effects, pros and cons:

- The native `@table` class/methods are now shadowed, try e.g. `which table -all`. However, this effect is quite clear, easily detectable and easily removed (delete destintation and remove path);
- No weird conflicts between native `@table` (now shadowed) and new `@table`;
- All methods, new and old, are visible, try `methods(table)`;
- Private table methods are accessible...
- ... but you are forced to use them.
- Exposing the new methods (user-implemented) to the private ones requires more maintenance and direct handling of version conflicts in the table implementations.
- You need write permissions on some eligible destination.

For those interested about the details, you can look into, https://github.com/okomarov/tableutils. Specifically the `install_tableutils` (the readme might not be updated).

Comment: The precedence order has nothing to do with the alphabet. The page you link to back that up doesn’t mention alphabetical order either. Directories are added to the `path` in a specific order. If you put your new `@table` before everything else (`addpath dir -begin`) it will have precedence.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for noticing that. I can't recall exactly why I mentioned the alphabetic precedence and I would usually test some statement like that. However, your comment sounds logically more relevant and there is indeed no explicit mention of alphabetic precedence in the docs. So, I might have personally preferred to control precedence with the alphabetic sorting rather than with the `path`, which now sounds like a big no, no... :)

Comment: Why do you say it’s a big no, no? It is a consistent and safe way of establishing a strict ordering. Alphabetical order changes with locale, so it would be bad to use that, IMO (i.e. move to a different country with your computer, and have MATLAB suddenly pick different functions!)

Comment: I meant alphabetic ordering is a big no no!

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

1. Define a modified `disp` function, say `disp_modified.m`, as follows, and put it in your path:

   ```
   function disp_modified(t)
   if istable(t)
       %// Do whatever you want to display tables
       builtin('disp', '''disp'' function intercepted!')
   else
       %// For non-tables, call `disp` normally
       builtin('disp', t)
   end
   ```
2. Define `disp` as a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) to the modifed function (you can do that in `startup.m` to always have it by default):

   ```
   disp = @disp_modified;
   ```

After this, in the command window I get

```
>> disp(1:5)
     1     2     3     4     5
>> disp({1 2 3 'bb'})
    [1]    [2]    [3]    'bb'
>> disp(table(rand(1e3,1)))
'disp' function intercepted!
```

Comment: This requires you to explicitly call `disp`. I believe he's wanting to overload `table`'s internal call to disp which will always (regardless of your local functions) use the builtin `disp`. This is at least what would be required to prevent what happens when you omit a semicolon.

Comment: This solution is quite hacky. It does not intercept implicit `disp()` by missing `;` and potentially encourages a dangerous practice. Also, it is not scalable and temporary. What should I do after a `clear`? Redefining all disp-like variables for each method?

Comment: Instead of calling the function `disp_modified` you could call it `disp`, then it is not affected by clear.

Comment: @Daniel Have you tried? It still calls `table.disp()` first (try palcing a breakpoint there). Although the `which disp -all` returns the new `disp()` first.

Comment: @Oleg: My matlab version is to old to support `table`, I just assumed it would solve the issue with `clear` like it would for other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage of the new class perhaps you could follow a cleaner approach. The proposed approach described in your post has the drawback that perhaps code used in your updated environment would not be easily portable to a new environment, or a program executed in your environment may demonstrate different behavior in a different environment.

Some questions you could consider (and perhaps clarify) would be: How do you intend to use the new class? Do you want to replace all the existing table uses? Do you want to be able to use it instead of a table class argument? Or do you want to alter the table so that each usage of the original table class in your environment uses the new class.

If you just need a new improved table for your usage, you could consider encapsulating the original table class in a new class. E.g MyTable, delegate all the methods you do not need to the original table methods, replace the methods you would like to improve or add new ones.

Update: Just saw the complete solution in Github and understood what you intended to do. Nice work. I will leave the post in case anyone finds it useful.

Comment: As I state in my first sentence, the table class is sealed, hence I cannot subclass it. Also, I am not quite sure what you mean by "portable to a new environment". I do say that one of the cons of my solution is the explicit need to deal with changes in matlab versions that affect the table class. As per the OS, it is up to each method to preserve compatibility (so it affects any solution). The use I want to make is listed in points 1 and 2 of the questions.

Comment: 1. By the phrase "solution easily portable to a new environment" I mean "to be able to use your solution in a new environment with the least possible effort". Having seen your solution I think it is easily portable.

2. I did not mean to subclass table. Just to create a new class (without sub-classing the original "table"), create identical method signatures, and add your own methods to be able to use this new table in your code. The drawback would be that it would not be a subclass of table. Perhaps this solution does not have all the properties you want.